# Re-Process Guards for current route in Angular 2/4+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-observable

I am currently working on an application that has several different streams of data, all of which change the state of the application per the user sitting in front of the screen. I have route guards setup that provide authorization, but am wondering if there is a way to "re-process" the route guards for the current route....say when a new value comes through on an observable?

Comment: Right after posting I did realize that I could just reinstate the current route, which "I think" would reprocess the guards....giving it a try now.

Comment: Scratch that. It's a service that's being used at multiple level throughout the application. I am beginning to think that this might not be the right approach altogether.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to re-execute a route guard each time the route changes? That is its normal behavior. It should re-execute the guards when the route changes. Could you provide some code, such as your route configuration, to help us help you?

Comment: No I was wanting to take the current route, and make sure that it was still valid. I use async data in several guards to check validity (authorization) within the database. I ended up using websockets to issue a change request that triggers any necessary actions within the application, depending on who is logged in.

Comment: A guard is supposed to not let the route to be activated. How exactly a guard is supposed to be applied when it's already activated?  If it is supposed to be reprocessed, it should be a service that is shared by both a component and its guard.

Comment: Thanks everyone, like I said above, I think initially my thought on how to approach this particular issue was better solved using websockets. Basically what I was trying to do was trigger a password reset on a given user when logged in. If a password reset request has been issued in the database the guard would not pass. But rather, I used a websocket to issue the request, immediately redirecting the user to the reset password page.